# chef: installing a package on windows

Tags: chef-infra

I am  trying chef on windows for the first time.
here is basic simple install for notepad++:

```
windows_package 'notepad' do  
  source 'c:/temp/npp.exe'  
  action :install  
end
```

It is giving  error while running chef-client.

> Installer type for Windows Package 'notepad' not specified and cannot
>   be determined from file extension 'exe'

Not sure what is missing.

Comment: just tried to install "putty" and got this error:                                            [2016-01-17T21:44:32-05:00] FATAL: RuntimeError: windows_package[putty] (windows_test::adobe line 40) had an error: Runt imeError: Unable to find a Chef::Provider::Package::Windows provider for installer_type 'inno' –

Answer (score 1):

Chef tries to autodetect the type of installer but it has failed in this case so you'll need to manually specify an `installer_type` property. See https://docs.chef.io/resources/windows_package.html#examples for some examples, or further up that page for details on `installer_type`.

Comment: @codetanger, Thx for reply, As you suggested I tried with installed_type but below code didn't work as well,    windows_package 'putty' do   source 'c:/temp/putty.exe'   installer_type :inno  action :install  end     Getting this error: [2016-01-17T21:44:32-05:00] FATAL: RuntimeError: windows_package[putty] (windows_test::adobe line 40) had an error: Runt imeError: Unable to find a Chef::Provider::Package::Windows provider for installer_type 'inno

Comment: You'll need to be running the latest Chef (12.6.0) for that to be supported.

Comment: that is right, server  had  12.4.1 agent which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update,  Issue was due to older chef-client installed on the server, after upgrading the client it is resolved..